# Redirect to https://www in web.config

Tags: web-config, iis-10

I'd like both example.com and www.example.com to be redirected to https://www.example.com

At the moment, I have these two rules in my web.config:

```
<rule name="HTTP/S to HTTPS Redirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
          <add input="{SERVER_PORT_SECURE}" pattern="^0$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
<rule name="Root Redirect to www" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
                        <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                            <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.*)://" />
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.).*" />
                        </conditions>
                    </rule>
```

Is it possible to combine them, so the user only experiences one redirect?

Update:
This seems to do the trick:

```
<rules>
<clear />
    <rule name="Redirect non-www OR non-https to https://www">
                  <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
    </rules>
```

Any downsides?